# What series connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification

I desoldered a bunch of connectors (out of a Baird VHS player IIRC) long ago and never made an effort to find out what they are. The only markings I can find on them are a very faint `SMK` on the underside of the moulding. I looked around SMK's website but they only show current products. Is there a legacy datasheet/series identifier for these connectors? I'd like to at least try and get hold of some wire-end parts to recycle the collection of PCB ends that I have.

[image]

Comment: There’s only one sensible place to recycle old connectors when there is no strong forward plan to put a sensible use to them......

Comment: Have you measured the pitch?  That's the best starting point.

Comment: @jonathanjo They're 2.5 or 2.54mm pitch. I can fit them through the holes in some prototyping board.

Comment: @Andyaka I've had them using up prime parts drawer space for like 10 years. Would be nice to give them a better sendoff than a garbage bag ;)